# SQL: My With statement not working inside while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am pretty new to sql queries 
I have a with statement inside stored procedure and after it i have a while loop 
then inside the while loop i am selecting the with statement to show it.

but it says

> invalid object.

my code is

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i=0
BEGIN
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT * FROM Dams)
WHILE @i<3
BEGIN
Select * from t1
SET @i = @i+1
END
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the select query after the common table expression:

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i=0
BEGIN
    WHILE @i<3
    BEGIN
        WITH t1 AS (
        SELECT * FROM Dams)    
        Select * from t1

        SET @i = @i+1
    END
END
```

Comment: It worked perfectly Thank you.
But I have a question.
If I have 2 with statements and I do want to do 2 selects it gives me same error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `while` loop for this.

In fact, you can simply do:

```
select d.*
from dams d cross join
     (values (0), (1), (2)) v(i);
```

Comment: yeah that is right but I need to do update 3 times 
not select.

Comment: @ahmad . . . That is not the question that you asked.  In all likelihood, you don't need `while` with `update` either.

Comment: Hi @Gordon.
I know it is not the question, I have select statement and update statement inside the while.
the error occurred in the select statement.

Comment: can you please advise how to do update statement from with statement ?

Comment: @ahmad . . . You should ask a question that clearly specified what you really need.